# Ugh, dismissing uiviewcontrollers and imagePickerController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

Here's my set-up:

Nav Controller: ViewcontrollerA -> ViewControllerB

ViewcontrollerB displays a imagePickerController, setting itself as Delegate

If the user hits CANCEL from the UIImagePicker, I was to dismiss ViewControllerB completely, popping the user back to ViewControllerA.

In:

```
-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
```

I have called:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

and

```
[[self parentViewController]  dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

and

```
[[[self parentViewController] parentViewController]  dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

No luck, ViewControllerB still hangs around.

How to I completely dismiss B programmatically from itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is ViewControllerA presenting ViewControllerB or is ViewControllerB being pushed via your navigation controller? It sounds like it's being pushed. In this case I would try

```
[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Edit for clarity:
You do want to dismiss the image picker the way you already are. You want to use `popViewControllerAnimated` to get rid of ViewControllerB.

Answer (score 0):

> The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view
>   controller it presented. If you call this method on the presented view
>   controller itself, it automatically forwards the message to the
>   presenting view controller.

```
[self.presentingViewController  dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```